# Си: выделение памяти внутри фукции

Tags: c, malloc

Пишу на голом Си, система Debian, в качестве IDE используется Code Blocks.

Допустим, в функцию передаётся указатель, в который выделяется память. В упрощённом виде:

```
void func(int* pointer){
pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
*pointer = 8;
}
```

Пока действие происходит внутри функции, всё нормально. Но при выходе из функции выделенная память стирается. Это, конечно хорошо, снижает количество утечек. Но есть ли возможность выделить память в указатель через функцию другим способом, кроме как через оператор return? Ведь, например, этот указатель вообще может быть глобальным, и функция будет работать только с ним, не имея никаких параметров.

**UPD:** знающие люди уже поправили меня, что память не стирается - исчезает указатель на неё. То есть происходит утечка памяти.
Если у меня есть глобальная переменная-указатель, и функция будет работать только с ней, и я не хочу передавать его в качестве аргумента:

```
int* pointer = NULL;
void pointer_alloc(int blocks){
pointer = malloc(sizeof(int) * blocks);
}
```

то как мне быть? После выхода из функции указатель теряет связь с выделенной под него памятью.

Comment: **выделенная память стирается** - ничего не стирается, ваша функция - просто утечка памяти... А вообще - вопрос задан как-то не совсем корректно...

Comment: *"при выходе из функции выделенная память стирается"* - ничего подобного, на самом деле при выходе из функции вы теряете указатель на выделенные данные, и происходит утечка памяти.

Comment: Покажите вызов функции, тогда можно будет дать более объективный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Передайте в функцию указатель на указатель - и будет вам счастье.

```
void func(int** pointer)
{
    *pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **pointer = 8;
}

void caller()
{
   int* alpha;
   func(&alpha);
   printf("%d\n", **alpha); // выводит 8
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за этот совет, я им обязательно воспользуюсь. Но как быть, если, например, указатель является глобальной переменной, и функция работает только с ним? Можно ли сразу ссылаться на этот указатель в теле функции, или без указания параметра не обойтись?

Comment: Не используйте глобальные переменные, они затрудняют поддержку кода.

Comment: даже глобальные константы?

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин «в военное время значение числа Пи может достигать четырёх» :)

Comment: @andreymal а теперь для тупых обьясни)